# Using YouTube Player API in Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use the Youtube player API inside my chrome packaged app with no luck, apparently I can't load external content in any way other than using webview tag and I also can't change the Content Security Policy settings (unlike chrome extensions) - is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure a webview is the way to do this, and to my knowledge there isn't any other way. It would help if you could explain why in your app a webview isn't a workable approach.

Comment: I can load a single video with the webview but if I wanted to use the full functionality of the API (events like onStateChange) It won't let me load external JS files.
I also tried to download and include those files locally, didn't work.